# Recibir sms desde el emulador de Android, en adb o Android Studio

Tags: android, adb, sms

Necesito recibir un sms enviado desde el emulador de Android en adb o una conexión TCP.

Por ejemplo, para enviar un sms al emulador todo lo que hay que hacer es iniciar una conexión telnet al puerto del emulador:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

Luego en la conexión enviar el comando:

```
sms send 123456 Texto del mensaje
```

Y se recibe el sms en el emulador. Lo que quiero hacer es lo opuesto, enviar desde el emulador y recibirlo en consola.

Ya se que pueden enviarse sms entre dos emuladores, pero eso no es lo que necesito.